# logback.xml springproperty: How to decrpyt password

Tags: spring-boot, logback, jasypt

We are using spring-boot and logback and store database username & encrypted password in spring application.yaml. How we can get the decrypted password in logback.xml so dbAppender can connect to database?

Thank you for help.

application.yaml

```
datasource:
        username: root
        password: ENC(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

logback.xml

```
    <springProperty scope="context" name="db.user" source="datasource.username"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="db.password" source="datasource.password"/>
    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
      <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
      <url>jdbc:mysql://host_name:3306/datebase_name</url>
      <username>${db.user}</username>
      <password>${db.password}</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For encrypting property, please use [Encryption and Decryption](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_encryption_and_decryption).

For using properties in logback please see [Logback extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logback-extensions).

However,  you can't actually make it in `logback-spring.xml`. Cause it's initialized too early and the encrypted properties are not ready. Please see [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/398).